# What is the difference between these PHP include statements?

Tags: php, scripting, include, require

1. `include("somefile.php");`
2. `include_once("somefile.php");`
3. `require("somefile.php");`
4. `require_once("somefile.php");`

What is the difference between these?

Comment: Man the difference is clearly explained in the manual. Why not to look there?

Comment: That's the second person to get bent out of shape about this question. As far as beginner questions go, this is seriously not bad at all; I'd rather read this then another "Why does that variable have two *s in front of it instead of one?"

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It doesn't matter if it is in the documentation or not. It's a perfectly legitimate question! Also, some people are overwhelmed by documentation.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Please, [educate yourself on the choices the community made about these kind of issues and accept them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions). If you are not happy with it, bring it up on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). This is not the place for this kind of discussion.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: More on this decision [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8678/disallowing-questions-that-can-be-easily-googled-or-answered-by-rtfm) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers).

Comment: @Andrew Please, learn to read. Nobody talking here of google. And the manual page always be higher in the google suggestions. And manual does change and your copypasted answer is not. And direct answer cannot be an ultimate source of knowledge, but of ignorance. And ignorant lemmings just trample me up on your meta, like you trampled the other guy here.

Comment: @Col The first link in his second comment was titled "Disallowing questions that can be easily googled or answered by RTFM". RTFM is exactly what you said, albeit phrased nicer

Comment: @Michael Well, it was a comment, not answer from me. And you have trampled non-RTFM answer anyway. And SO will never be a better source of information, just because man being written by pros and SO answers being written by same lamers who ask.

Comment: Plus, this zillion-times-answered-already lame question can't add anything to the Ultimate Knowledge Database.

Comment: @col at some point you are either part of the problem (by adding noise like this) or part of the solution. Which is it?

Comment: @Jeff depends on the problem and point of view. What SO want to be is one. What's it become as a fact - is another. To be the real source of knowledge, 9 of 10 questions should be closed as too localized or exact duplicate. Otherwise people will always take SO as just "do-my-job-for-free service", not as the database. Wikipedia doesn't have 100 articles on the same topic. That's the ultimate difference. And what SO does with it's "answer every question in the world, no matter how lame is it" is another problem. To me, "direct answer at any cost" and "Rep is the only value" principles ARE noise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between [`include()`](http://php.net/include) and [`require()`](http://php.net/require) is that the [`include()`](http://php.net/include) construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from [`require()`](http://php.net/require), which will emit a fatal error (and stop the execution of the script).

[`include_once()`](http://php.net/include_once) and [`require_once()`](http://php.net/require_once) has the exact same behavior than [`include()`](http://php.net/include) and [`require()`](http://php.net/require), except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

[`include_once()`](http://php.net/include_once) and [`require_once()`](http://php.net/require_once) is especially useful in cases where you are including files containing class and/or function definitions. It prevents you from accidentally including the same file twice and causing "double definition" errors.